# Set innerHTML of a div to = multiple array items using getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I'm trying to finish with the html `<div id="animal"> Dog Cat Horse </div>` but i can't figure out how to combine multiple array elements into one innerHTML. I'm trying something like this:

```js
var myArray = [
  ['Dog', 'Terrier'],
  ['Cat', 'Tabby'],
  ['Horse', 'Shetland'],
];

for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById('animal').innerHTML = locations[i][0];
};
```

```html
    <div id="animal"> animal names here </div>
```

Comment: Typo: `locations` -> `myArray`. Also, use `+=` to append, as `=` will overwrite, and use `textContent` instead of `innerHTML` if not dealing with HTML.

Comment: you could loop through your array and assign all elements to a string, then  assign it to the innerHTML

Comment: @Seth Please be careful with code edits. You might just have edited out the core problem of the question.

Comment: @Siguza Understood. I think the issue is actually the concatenation, not the var name. But I switched back to preserve the original.

Comment: @Siguza Or `insertAdjacentHTML`, which is faster than `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are replacing the content of your div in each iteration in the loop.

Ideal way would be to create a string of your data and append that in you div. Instead of accessing the `dom` in each iteration

```js
var myArray = [
  ['Dog', 'Terrier'],
  ['Cat', 'Tabby'],
  ['Horse', 'Shetland'],
];
var data = "";
for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  data += " " +  myArray[i][0];
};

document.getElementById('animal').innerHTML = data;
```

```html
<div id="animal"> animal names here </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're currently overwriting the contents of `#animal` with every iteration, so only the last item is displayed. You need to concatenate the `innerHTML` of `#animal` so that the new items are appending to the existing html. Also note that you can add additional HTML such as a `<br/>` tag to split the lines up for readability.

```js
var myArray = [
  ['Dog', 'Terrier'],
  ['Cat', 'Tabby'],
  ['Horse', 'Shetland'],
];

for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById('animal').innerHTML += myArray[i][0] + "</br>";
};
```

```html
    <div id="animal"></div>
```

Lastly, the markup for outputting your animals looks like a job for an ordered/unordered list. Additionally as @kb pointed out, it's better to take a more modern and idiomatic approach and use [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and as @ gcampbell pointed out, [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) is faster than `innerHTML`

```js
var animals = [
  ['Dog', 'Terrier'],
  ['Cat', 'Tabby'],
  ['Horse', 'Shetland'],
];


var animalNames = animals.map(function(animal) {
    return "<li>" + animal[0] + "</li>";
  })
  .join("");

document.getElementById('animal').insertAdjacentHTML('beforebegin', animalNames);
```

```html
<h3>Animals:</h3>
<ul id="animal"></ul>
```

Comment: Has the Javascript scene moved so far from it's programming roots that nobody masters foundations like `.map()` anymore? Every single answer in this thread relies on for-looping an array for no apparent reason. It's a little disheartening.

Comment: I agree with you and hardly ever use for loops, personally. But the reason you're seeing these within the answers is to answer the OP's question with *their* code. Perhaps they support legacy browsers and don't want the overhead of a polyfill for `Array.prototype.map` and other enumerable methods. Not to mention that the foundations are built on for/while loops. Check out the polyfill for `.map`. It's also worthy to point out that a for loop is completely acceptable and sometimes even necessary. In this case, there are alternatives, but that's not the root of the OPs problem.

Comment: Updated second option to use map... just for you ;)

Comment: Sweet! And you absolutely have a point, but I feel SO is the right place to not just take things at face value from OP but also make suggestions and show alternatives. In this case it was more the volume of for-loop answers and the total lack of other suggestions that struck me, even though I absolutely agree that the format of OP's original code should not be assumed to be "senseless" in that sometimes it might be "bad" for reasons like the ones you mentioned. Didn't mean to come off as pissy, your answer was great.

Answer (score -1):

When you use `innerHTML =`, it replaces all the HTML in an element. You need to use `+=` too add to the inner HTML.

```
for (i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById('animal').innerHTML+= ' ' + myArray[i][0]; 
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use array to string conversion

```
document.getElementById('animal').innerHTML = myArray.toString().replace(",", " ")
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/scsiva1991/04r74oeg/)

Answer (score -2):

try something like that:

```
var myArray = [
[ 'Dog' , 'Terrier'],
[ 'Cat' , 'Tabby' ],
[ 'Horse' , 'Shetland'],
];

var myStr;

mtStr =""

for (i = 0; i < myArray.length-1; i++) { 
    myStr += myArray[i];
 }

document.getElementById('animal').innerHTML= myStr;
```